# How to display Console to Service Cloud User License?

Tags: profile, console

We just bought Service Cloud Licenses...we already have a console that was in use by Sales Cloud users + Feature Licenses but now we would like to create a profile for Service Cloud Users that includes access to a console.

So a profile exists titled "service cloud user" with access to the "Call Centre".  If I extend this proofile to include things like manage reports /dashboards as these are necessary to display a Console app (judging by the errors) the apps don't display.  If I clone this and extend it to allow visibility to our Console App the apps simply don't display.  I have also tried adding a new app to the default Service Cloud Profile and this doesn't work either.

What do I have to add to enable the/a Console for Service Cloud Profiles?

Thanks - I think i am missing something obvious.

Note - the service cloud tick box under each user is not available if they are linked to a service cloud profile.

2nd Note - the service cloud feature liceses (enabled via the tick box mentioned in the note) still have access to the console apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Permission Sets for most of the setting for any profile.

1. Setup
2. Manage Users
3. Permission Sets

There there are a lot configurations that you can set and latter add to any profile. For the Service Cloud User you need to do that on the User page, you can't add it to the permission set as far as I know.

[Assign the Service Cloud Feature License to Users](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_assign_service_feature_license.htm)

To enable the service cloud you need to follow a number of steps and configurations for he UI, please check and follow this documentation:

[Service Cloud Workbook](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/workbook_service_cloud.pdf)

I highly recommend you to follow the workbook because there are an important number of settings that you need to be aware of. Good luck!

Comment: So u still use the feature licenses via the tick box on the user record? U don't bother creating a  profile using the service cloud license? That's what it sounds like in the workbook...

Comment: Essentially how do I use a service cloud user license to display a console?

Comment: You don't need a permission set, you can just tick the Service Cloud User and that will do it. 
 
You need to set up the console first. To do that you need to follow the instructions on the workbook. There are to many steps to explain it here. Follow the workbook and you will learn how to do it.

Comment: Yeah that was all fine - I just expected the Profiles which are based on "Service Cloud User Licenses" to also have access to the consoles...but they don't appear to (because the service cloud user tick box is disabled).  Sorry it just seems like standard functionality to me?